# NO routes match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am trying to implement collection routes but getting this error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/api/users/editProfile"):
  path/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  path/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
  path/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  path/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  path/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  path/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  path/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  path/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  path/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  path/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  path/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  path/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  path/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  path/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  path/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  path/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  path/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
  path/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  path/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  path/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  path/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  path/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  path/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered path/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered path/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (6.2ms)
  Rendered path/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered path/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered path/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (62.4ms)
```

```
 resources :users do
            collection do
              post '/users/editProfile' => 'users#update'
            end
          end
```

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::ApisController
    skip_before_action :authenticate_user, :except => [:destroy]
    before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


     def update
        @user.attributes = user_params
        @user.skip_password_validation = true
        if @user.save
            render :json => {result: true,:object => @user}
        else
            render :json => {result: false,status: INVALID_CREDENTAILS_STATUS,:object => @user.errors.full_messages}
        end     
    end

    private

        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:email,:password,:password_confirmation,:first_name,:last_name,:mobile_number,:landline_number,:office_number ,:profile )
        end

 end
```

Comment: Post the exact error you are getting please.

Comment: okay i am posting the exact error

Comment: Also post the output from 'rake routes' (command line)

Comment: You don't need to add `'users/'` when using a collection. It should be just `'/editProfile'`

Comment: A `collection` route is supposed to operate on multiple users, your `UsersController#update` method is only going to work with one user. Perhaps you want a `member` route to work with only one user, or you need to make `update` take multiple users.

Comment: okay i will keep that in mind

Comment: What is unusual is sending /users/editProfile to Update rather than Edit action. You update action should update passed params. Edit should send a view with a form to declare the params..

Answer (score 0):

Just write
post '/editProfile' => 'users#update'
instead of
post '/users/editProfile' => 'users#update'